# Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01,code=2)

Tags: hive

I was executing a hive job successfully but since last day it is giving me an error after mapper job is completed below are the logs and query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE zong_dwh.TEMP_P_UFDR_imp6 
SELECT
  from_unixtime(begin_time+5*3600,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Date1,
  from_unixtime(begin_time+5*3600,'HH') AS Hour1, 
  MSISDN AS MSISDN,
  A.prot_type AS Protocol, 
  B.protocol as Application,
  host AS Domain,
  D.browser_name AS browser_type, 
  cast (null as varchar(10)) as media_format, 
  C.ter_type_name_en as device_category, 
  C.ter_brand_name as device_brand, 
  rat as session_technology, 
  case 
    when rat=1 then Concat(mcc,mnc,lac,ci) 
    when rat=2  then Concat(mcc,mnc,lac,sac) 
    when rat=6 then concat(mcc,mnc,eci) 
  end AS Actual_Site_ID,
  sum(coalesce(L4_DW_THROUGHPUT,0)+coalesce(L4_UL_THROUGHPUT,0)) as total_data_volume,
  sum(coalesce(TCP_UL_RETRANS_WITHPL,0)/coalesce(TCP_DW_RETRANS_WITHPL,1)) AS retrans_rate, 
  sum(coalesce(DATATRANS_UL_DURATION,0) + coalesce(DATATRANS_DW_DURATION,0)) as duration, 
  count(sessionkey) as usage_quantity,
  round(sum(L4_DW_THROUGHPUT)/1024/1024,4)/sum(end_time*1000+end_time_msel-begin_time*1000-begin_time_msel) AS downlink_throughput,
  round(sum(L4_UL_THROUGHPUT)/1024/1024,4)/sum(end_time*1000+end_time_msel-begin_time*1000-begin_time_msel) as uplink_throughput 
from 
  ps.detail_ufdr_http_browsing_17923 A 
  INNER JOIN ps.dim_protocol B ON   B.protocol_id=A.prot_type 
  INNER JOIN ps.dim_terminal C on substr(A.imei,1,8)=C.tac 
  inner join ps.dim_browser_type D on A.browser_type=D.browser_type_id  
Group by
  from_unixtime(begin_time+5*3600,'yyyy-MM-dd'),
  from_unixtime(begin_time+5*3600,'HH'),MSISDN,
  prot_type,
  B.protocol,
  host,
  D.browser_name,
  cast (null as varchar(10)),
  C.ter_type_name_en,
  C.ter_brand_name,
  rat,
  case 
    when rat=1 then Concat(mcc,mnc,lac,ci)  
    when rat=2  then Concat(mcc,mnc,lac,sac) 
    when rat=6 then concat(mcc,mnc,eci)  
  end;
```

Logs :

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
>   while processing row (tag=0)
>   {"key":{"_col0":"2019-02-11","_col1":"05","_col2":"3002346407","_col3":146,"_col4":"","_col5":null,"_col6":null,"_col7":"35538908","_col8":6,"_col9":"","_col10":"","_col11":"","_col12":"0ED1102"},"value":{"_col0":75013,"_col1":4.0,"_col2":2253648000,"_col3":5,"_col4":0}}
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:182) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1769)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:176) Caused
>   by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime
>   Error while processing row (tag=0)
>   {"key":{"_col0":"2019-02-11","_col1":"05","_col2":"3002346407","_col3":146,"_col4":"","_col5":null,"_col6":null,"_col7":"35538908","_col8":6,"_col9":"","_col10":"","_col11":"","_col12":"0ED1102"},"value":{"_col0":75013,"_col1":4.0,"_col2":2253648000,"_col3":5,"_col4":0}}
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
>   ... 7 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute
>   method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFConv.evaluate(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable,org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable)
>   on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFConv@2e2f720 of class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFConv with arguments
>   {:org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, 16:org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable,
>   10:org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable} of size 3 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1034)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge.evaluate(GenericUDFBridge.java:182)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeGenericFuncEvaluator.java:193)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:104)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:838)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:1019)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:821)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processKey(GroupByOperator.java:695)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.process(GroupByOperator.java:761)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:235)
>   ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.invoke(FunctionRegistry.java:1010)
>   ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFConv.evaluate(UDFConv.java:160) ...
>   23 more

Comment: there are 2 issues, first one is privilege access, do you still have access to the db where you are trying to insert the data

Comment: Hi,above issue has been resolved, problem was incompatibility of CONV function with hive